# Linear Algebra,Conjugate Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, inner-products, trace

Let $ M_n(\mathbb C) $ be the space of all $ n\times n $ matrices with complex entries. Prove that function $ \langle, \rangle : M_n(\mathbb C) \times M_n(\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C $ defined by $ \langle A, B\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A^∗B) $, is an inner product, where $ A^* $ is conjugate transpose of $ A $.

Comment: I tried to solve it by using definition of matrix product and i figured out <A,A> >= 0, so it satisfied the first condition of being inner product. I need to show <A,B>=conjugate(<B,A>) and <A,B,C>=<A,B>+<A,C>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove that

1. $ \mathrm{Tr}(A^*A) \ge 0; $
2. $\mathrm{Tr}(A^*A) = 0 \iff A = 0; $
3. $ \mathrm{Tr}(A^*(B + C)) = \mathrm{Tr}(A^*B) + \mathrm{Tr}(A^*C); $
4. $ \mathrm{Tr}(A^*(zB)) = z\,\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B) $
5. $ \mathrm{Tr}(A^*B) = \left(\mathrm{Tr}(B^*A)\right)^* $

For (1) just notice that $ A^*A $ is positive semidefinite, thus has non negative eigenvalues and non negative trace; also, if the trace is zero all the eigenvalues need to be zero, and thus $ A^*A = 0 $, which is only possible if $ A = 0 $.

Items (3) and (4) are trivially verified because the trace is linear.

For (5), just write out the trace explicitly, apply the linearity of complex conjugation and you get the thesis.

Comment: Your explanation is great, thank you for this but is there any way to solve this without using eigen values/vectors?

Comment: @Linearr: There is the following, more explicit proof; you denote $ a_{ij} := (e_i)^T Ae_j $ you have $ \mathrm{Tr}(A^*A) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n{\bar{a}_{ij}a_{ij}} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n{|a_{ij}|^2} $. This is apparently $ \ge 0 $ and $ \ne 0 $ unless all $ a_{ij} $ are zero (in which case $ A = 0 $). This is called *Frobenius product*, and it basically means summing over all the elements of a matrix (treat a matrix as if it were a vector, in a way).